# Create a file with the help of reference file in PHP

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I have 2 files.

1. `source.txt`

```
name: foo
dob: ---
```

2. `reference.txt`

```
name: foo
dob: 11-Aug-2017

name: bar
dob: 15-Aug-2017
```

Generate file `target.txt` like:

```
name: foo
dob: 11-Aug-2017
```

Search strings from `source.txt` like `name: NAME` and match it in  `reference.txt` file and replace it.

Search

```
name: foo
dob:
```

Replace with

```
name: foo
dob: 11-Aug-2017
```

---

I have tried below code which searches the target string `name: foo`. But, Could not generate expected output.

```
$url = 'reference.txt';

if( is_file( $url ) ) {

    $handle = fopen( $url, "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

            if( substr($line, 0, strlen('name: foo')) === 'name: foo' ) {
                // Found record 'name: foo'
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way i didnt get what you want exactly but 
  this example  may be help you to search a string in a file  :

```
 <?php
    $searchthis = "mystring";
    $matches = array();

    $handle = @fopen("path/to/inputfile.txt", "r");
    if ($handle)
    {
        while (!feof($handle))
        {
            $buffer = fgets($handle);
            if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE)
                $matches[] = $buffer;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    //show results:
    print_r($matches);
    ?>
```

Comment: Actually I want to replace multiple lines from 1 file into another.

Comment: ah so you can use  str_replace() and i guess it's the solution jut try it